# Call same code for two Sublasses

Tags: ruby

I have three Classes `Base::Builder`, `Base::Builder::Car`and  `Base::Builder::House`

Lets suppose I have this code that I want to shorten:

```
Base::Builder::Car
  .new(@build_plan)
  .generate

Base::Builder::House
  .new(@build_plan)
  .generate
```

What I did was:

```
 [Base::Builder::Car, Base::Builder::House].each do |builder|
   builder.new(@build_plan)
          .generate 
 end
```

**But I dont really like this refactoring, because like this, It gets unreadable**

How would you Refactor this Code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of explicitly specifying all the subclasses you could look them up dynamically like this:

```
 ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |klass| klass < Base::Builder }.each do |builder|
   builder.new(@build_plan)
   .generate 
 end
```

This is of course only useful if you really want to select *all* the subclasses. And it's not very readable.

Whether this is actually practical depends on your use case.